# I need to end Game over or continue While loop for class

Tags: java, eclipse

For my class we need to make a dice game, I made I version of war, I need a little help finishing it. I need to Display the final points and I would like it if somehow I could display the difference between the scores. I also do not know how to end the game over loop.

```
public class Game {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
       {
        Dice myDie = new Dice();
        Dice CompDie= new Dice();

        int player =0;
        int computer =0;
        boolean gameOver;
        do
        {
            int[] scores = new int[3];
            gameOver = false;
            while(!gameOver)
            {
                myDie.roll();
                System.out.println("You rolled a " + myDie.getValue());
                player = myDie.getValue();

                CompDie.roll();
                System.out.println("Computer rolled a " + CompDie.getValue());
                computer = CompDie.getValue();

                checkResults(player, computer, scores);
                printResults(scores);

                // ask player if want to continue enter Y to continue
                System.out.println("Do you want to continue playing enter Y if so");    // I need to end loop here




            }

       }while(keepPlaying());








       }
    public static boolean keepPlaying()
    {
        Scanner readIn = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean playAgain = false; 
        System.out.println("Do you want to play again?");
        String answer = readIn.nextLine().toUpperCase();
        char ans = answer.charAt(0);
        if(ans == 'Y')
            playAgain = true;
        return playAgain;

    }
    public static void checkResults(int player, int computer, int[] scores)
    {
        if(player > computer)
        {
            scores[1]++;
        }
        else if(player < computer)
        {
            scores[2]++;
        }
        else
        {
            scores[0]++;
        }
    }
    public static void printResults(int[] list)
    {
        System.out.println("     Ties    Player   Computer");
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.printf("%8d", list[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: The innermost loop is completely unnecessary; you should get rid of it and have the code inside of it only in the first loop. You also need to initialize `scores` before the first loop, or else it will be re-created as a blank array every time the loop is run and won't retain the values previously added to it.

Comment: There is also no need to tag this with `eclipse` as this question has nothing to do with the IDE.

Comment: I finished  the loop and now I need to initialized scores like you said, how do I do that

Comment: `scores` is initialized here: `int[] scores = new int[3];`. Just move this line to be before the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
 while(!gameOver)
        {

        }
```

This loop is unnecessary and also never stops. If you still want it you need to set gameOver = true when you want to quit.

To show the difference between scores just subtract scores from each other and print it. `System.out.println(Math.abs(score[1] - score[2]));`
Something like this.

Comment: Okay but how can I take the input from the user when they hit Y to continue,